# Why can Javascript functions and labels be called let?

Tags: javascript, let

This may be off topic, but I've done extensive research and come up empty handed, and I want an answer. In Javascript, the keyword `let` can be used as a function name:

```
function let() {
  console.log("Hello world")
}
let()
// Prints "Hello world"
```

This doesn't work for `const`, a similar keyword also introduced in ES6. Keywords aren't allowed to be label names either, but `let` is also a valid label name, while other keywords produce errors. The MDN docs state that "In strict mode code, you can't use "let" as a label name. It will throw a SyntaxError (let is a reserved identifier)."
Why is this?

Comment: The short version is that `const` was listed in the ECMAScript 1st Edition as a "future reserved word" which meant it couldn't be used for identifiers; `let` wasn't. `let` wasn't mentioned as a possible reserved word until the 5th edition, and then only in strict mode code. (Your example doesn't work in strict mode.) Since `let` wasn't reserved, it was potentially used in code in widespread use, and couldn't be retroactively made a purely reserved word. So instead, it's still a valid identifier (in loose mode). The parser has to figure out whether it's a declaration or identifier by context.

Comment: JavaScript also has *contextual* reserved words. `async` is a valid identifier (even in strict mode, and even inside an `async` function), it only has special meaning in places where previously it would have been a syntax error for an identifier to be there. `await` is a valid identifier (even in strict mode), unless it's within an `async` function; then it's a reserved word. :-) `yield` is only a reserved word inside generator functions. Etc.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why other languages don't have something like "The Zen of Python" and end up a big mess. I like braces though.